# Setting up relay mail server

Tags: email, configuration, sendmail

I want to setup a mail relay server that can receive emails from particular domains and forward them to a central mail server which will deliver them to their destinations.

This is because the central mail server allows sending email only from authorized domains and to prevent flooding of the authorized domains list I have to setup a mail relay server which is added in list of authorized domains.

`sendmail` can be used for this (as my google searches suggest) but I could not find any good documentation on configuring `sendmail` to do this.

Can anyone suggest how to go about doing this?

Comment: Sendmail wouldn't be my first choice for doing this; it's configuration language will send you mad.  I say this without malice, just as an observation -- I spent several years managing sendmail boxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pretty much all you need to add to the sendmail.mc configuration on the relay server is

define(`SMART_HOST',`central.mail.server.address')dnl

to limit the domains that are allowed to send to the relay server, you'd add them to the sendmail access file (typically /etc/mail/access) as follows

Connect:first.allowed.domain.com     RELAY
Connect:second.allowed.domain.com    RELAY

etc.

Comment: Thankyou very much for quick help. It worked nicely. I have to get my relay server added up in the list of trusted senders :P  as it is showing `Recipient address rejected: Greylisted`.